# Apple METAL C++ problem with MTL::CopyAllDevices();

Tags: c++, metal

I'm trying to get C++ code working with Metal.

I get the array of `MTL:Device` by calling

```
NS::Array *device_array = MTL::CopyAllDevices();
```

Next, I want to get the only element of the `MTL::Device` array by calling

```
MTL::Device *device = device_array->object(0);
```

I get an error:

```
Cannot initialize a variable of type 'MTL::Device *' with an rvalue of type 'NS::Object *'
```

**Question:**

> how to get an MTL::Device object from NS::Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NS::Array` just contains `NS::Object`s, it doesn't know what it contains, therefore by default `.object(index)` returns `NS::Object*` which is a base class of `MTL::Device` and therefore not automatically castable. Fortunately `object` is a template so you can just do:

```
MTL::Device *device = device_array->object<MTL::Device>(0);
```

to retrieve the object with the correct class.

Note that this is just implemented with a `reinterpret_cast` so there is no checking that you've actually used the correct class so use with care!